# C# Throw Exception and catch in the same method why it's bad?

Tags: c#, .net, code-structure

Have some discussion about one implementation:

```
// Pseudocode
accessor type GetValue() 
{
    try
    {
        do some action with possible throw exception1
        do some action with possible throw exception2

        return value;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        value = default;
        throw Wraped in Meaningfull Exception ex

    }
}
```

Can someone explain why it might be a bad design, to use `try`-`catch` like that (throw and catch at the same method) to safely do some actions and agregate different type of similar exception?

Comment: This is not always a bad design and in some cases may be quite meaningful

Comment: it does not make a lot of sense for many reasons. For example by single responsibility principle if you validate some input arguments, throw an exception and catch it in the same method - you do a lot in this method or even in this class. You could do the same by simple `if` statements. Re-throwing is another case but I suggest to extract code where you throw exceptions in separate methods for better reading.

Comment: Catching *all* exceptions - `catch(Exception ex) {...}` that is a bad design. What if `ex` is `ArgumentNullException`? `AccessViolationException`?

Comment: @apomene Can you provide a example of a real use of that? I can't see a case that be useful. Only case is when you want to rethrow a exception from a thread to the main thread.

Comment: The only practical answer to this is "it depends" VTC

Comment: It can be a bad design only if you put everything inside only 1 try/catch that can trows  a lot of different exceptions, but in fact it could be ok, it depends

Comment: Can't say it's bad design unless we see the actual program it's used within. Sometimes people tend to follow rules without relating them to the logic of their programs which creates more problems than it solves.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko in current method id doesn't make any sense the type of exception

Comment: It is the kind of decision you learn to regret when this code is part of a program that fails on a hard-to-diagnose exception .  You then need to configure the debugger to stop on the "first chance" exception.  And it will stop in this code instead of the bad code.  It is also quite slow, especially so when you debug, roughly x100000 slower when the exception is thrown than setting a variable.  Boilerplate advice is always "don't use exceptions for flow control".

Comment: @HansPassant I've got your point, the debugging is always full of surprises. I totally agree with your point that it really 'bad practice' to use throws for flow control (the same ugly and confusing, as use GOTO), but in my case, it doesn't change the execution logic, it just catches 'ex' wrap it more meaningful and throw further. (DmitryBychenko) reply helps me to realize that there potentially could be other exceptions that can be hidden by wrapping it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not *rethrowing*

```
 throw new WrapedException("MyNewMessage", ex);
```

that is wrong but catching *all* the exceptions

```
 catch (Exception ex) {
   ...
 }
```

is a bad design: it *masks* potentially *dangerous behaviour*. Let's see why. Suppose we use `GetValue()` like this:

```
   try {
     someValue = GetValue();
   }
   catch (WrapedException) {  
     // We failed to obtain someValue;
     // The reason - WrapedException - is innocent
     // Let's use default value then

     someValue = defaultSomeValue;
   }
```

And the actual picture is

```
   public GetValue() {
     try {
       do some action with possible throw exception1

       // Catastrophy here: AccessViolationException! System is in ruins!
       do some action with possible throw exception2

       return value;
     }
     catch (Exception ex) { // AccessViolationException will be caught...
       // ...and the disaster will have been masked as being just WrapedException
       throw new WrapedException("MyNewMessage", ex);
     }
   }
```

Your design is OK if you catch only expected exception types:

```
   public GetValue() {
     try {
       do some action with possible throw exception1
       do some action with possible throw exception2

       return value;
     }
     catch (FileNotFound ex) {
       // File not found, nothing special in the context of the routine
       throw new WrapedException("File not found and we can't load the CCalue", ex);
     }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot make sense!

Comment: Basically it's in [official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/using-standard-exception-types)